# Как расширить функционал MessageBox.Show?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Хотелось бы на форму добавить еще кнопку свою и передать в метод делегат (со своим функционалом), который бы вызывался в момент нажатия этой новой кнопки.

Подскажите с чего начать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MessageBox` -- это по сути просто статический класс, который обращается к WinAPI и даже не является контролом. Поэтому расширить его, увы, не получится. Если хочется иметь кастомное окно сообщения, придется написать свою или поискать готовые реализации в интернете.